# Word that means something can be turned on or off

Tags: single-word-requests

This word would describe a car, light switch, computer, etc. because they can all be turned on or off. I thought of toggle-able, but that doesn't sound right on a couple levels.

Edit: I am hoping for something specific to the idea of 'on' or 'off', if it exists. For example, suppose you have two possible colors for some text in a website, lets say red and blue. You could have a button that toggles the text between the two options, but you wouldn't necessarily say that one is 'On' and the other is 'Off'. I feel that 'toggled' is more general and can refer to more states than just 'on' or 'off'.

Comment: If you like Destiny’s Child and Internet memes, you might get off with calling it _togglicious_.

Comment: What are the "couple of levels" why this doesn't sound right? That information would help the community avoid similar pitfalls. Also, please give the sentence where you intend to use the word (as requested in the tag description). [See the help text](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), particularly the four bullet points at the end.

Comment: @AndrewLeach First, it just sounds funny to my ears (Subjective I know, sorry). Second, I want the word to be specific to 'on'/'off' states and not general binary states like toggle seems to me.

Comment: "Switchable", perhaps?

Comment: @carrizal Since you have accepted an answer which majors on ***toggled*** but also includes three other solutions, could you comment on that answer to say which of those you have accepted?

Comment: The expression 'on/off' is commonly used adjectivally.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I accepted toggled. It isn't specific to on/off, but I gave up on anything that specific appearing and selected toggled.

Comment: As a programmer I would say it can be 'toggled'. But one could equally say depending on context it's 'settable'. The difference is that the latter could have more than one setting (not just on or off). You could say it's 'binary' too but that could also be more than 'turning on/off'. And yes: toggle can toggle more than just on and off but what is being toggled? A bit? Then it's being toggled on or off. Context is the key there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are along the right lines. I would say that something like a switch *can be **toggled***.

You can also say that it can be *switched on or off*. However, usually if you can switch something on, there is the case that you can also switch it off.

You may also have a context related word such as *flicked* for lights and *powered* for computers.

Answer (score 5):

"Toggle" assumes two modes of operation. Regardless of whether it controls On/Off or Red/Blue, the word "toggle" is perfectly apt. If there were more modes than two (i.e., if a single button cycled through red/blue/green text colors), then the word "toggle" would not be appropriate.

It is a toggle, it can be toggled, and though the words toggleable/togglable are correct, they're ugly and awkward. I'd use switchable, instead, for readability, as in "The toggle to the left affects the switchable font color."

Comment: **and though the words toggleable/togglable are correct, they're ugly and awkward** As a programmer I very much disagree there; that however is a matter of what one finds aesthetically appealing. Some would argue those aren't valid words but they certainly work. If not you could add a dash between. 'Switchable' could be used too to be sure but one could argue that it can do more than just 'on' or 'off' (just as 'toggle' but just as much as arguing semantics).

Answer (score 1):

[Togglable](http://www.wordsense.eu/togglable/) sounds perfectly fine to me

Source: http://www.wordsense.eu/togglable/

Answer (score 0):

If you were comparing things that can be turned on and off with things that can't, you could use "not continuously running" for the things that can be turned off and "continuously running" for the things that can't be turned off.